# Send data to activity when clicked on notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

i am opening a activity when notification is clicked . notification is activated from a service class .i want to send data to new activity opened from notification i am using  intent1.putExtra("lable",lable); but in new activity it is giving me nullpointer exeption.

```
 intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), simplestop.class);
            intent1.putExtra("lable",lable);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0); 
Notification mNotify  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title" + "!")
            .setContentText("Click me!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: Post the code where you are trying to get this extra.

Comment: Show us how you receive intent on new activity.

Comment: Show activity code where you retrieve the data

Comment: Show how do you retrieve data.

Comment: in other activity i am using this code to receive code in other activity    lable = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lable");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code for send data to `activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("from", "notification");
                    pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 3, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

May be you have problem in setting `flag=0` or try to change request `code=0` to any other integer.

Answer (score 0):

Sending data.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), simplestop.class);
intent.putExtra("lable", lable);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

final RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.yourLayoutOfNotification);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.IdOfTheItemYouClick, contentIntent);
```

Try to retrieve data something like this in your `simplestop.class`

```
if (getIntent().getDataString() == null) {
   String lable = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("lable");
 }
```

And I think you need to call the `onNewIntent` at the `simplestop.class`
And there to retrieve data.

And try to create a `Log` if the data are retrieved.

```
Log.d("Data", lable);
```

And tell what is the `Log` showing.

Comment: i already tried this and this is not working . i think problem is sending data